# Efficient data type to use for retrieving values of a key in lexicographical order in Redis?

Tags: c#, data-structures, hash, redis

I'm building a tagging system using [ServiceStack.Redis](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Redis/) in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23).
I want to retrieve `values` of a `key` in lexicographical order and it should be pretty fast.
`values` are of type `string` with an average length of 10 characters.

I was under the impression that `sorted set` in [redis](/questions/tagged/redis) stores the `values` based on lexicographical order but instead it uses the `score` (timestamp) but I was wrong.

Which data type should I choose?
Additionally data-type should support intersection like `SINTER` in `Sets`.

Answer (score 1):

You are right - Sorted Sets are what you need. To have the members in a Sorted Set ordered lexicographically, just set the all scores to 0. You can then use `ZRANGEBYLEX` as well as set operations.